# Reason why deep and shallow copy differences between "primitive" and "non-primitive" objects?

Tags: python, copy

I know the difference between shallow and deep copy in Python, and the question is not about when to use one or the other. However I find this trivial example pretty amusing and non-intuitive

```
from copy import deepcopy

 a=0
 b=deepcopy(a)
 c=a
 a+=1
 print(a,b,c)
```

output: 1 0 0

```
 from copy import deepcopy
 a=[0]
 b=deepcopy(a)
 c=a
 a[0]+=1
 print(a,b,c)
```

output: [1] 0 [1]

I would like to know the **reason why** this design choice was made, since the two snippets of code are in my opinion quite equivalent however their output is completely different. To make myself more explicit I wonder why = is a deepcopy in the case of a "primitive" variable  and a shallow copy in the case of a "non-primitive" (but still part of the basic language) variable like a list? I personally find this behavior counter-intuitive 
Note: I used python 3

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `c=a` isn't a shallow copy - it's even shallower than that. It only copies the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The catch here is **mutability** and **immutability**.

There is no such thing is primitive and non primitive in python, everything is a type, some are just inbuilt.

You need to understand how python stores data in variables. Assuming you come from a C background, you can think of all python variables are pointers.
**All python variables store the *reference* to the location where the value of the variable actually is**.

The builtin `id` function somewhat lets us look into where the value of a variable is actually stored.

```
>>> x = 12345678
>>> id(x)
1886797010128
>>> y = x
>>> id(y)
1886797010128
>>> y += 1
>>> y
12345679
>>> x
12345678
>>> id(y)
1886794729648
```

The variable `x` points to location `1886797010128` and location `1886797010128` holds the value of `10`. `int` is an immutable type in python, which means that the data stored in the location `1886797010128` can't be changed.

When we assign `y = x`, `y` now also points to the same address, since it's not necessary to allocate more memory for the same value.

When `y` is changed (remember that `int` is an immutable type and it's value can't be changed), a new int is created in the new location `1886794729648` and `y` now points to this new int object at the new address.

The same happens when you try to update the value of a variable that holds immutable data.

```
>>> id(x)
140707671077744
>>> x = 30
>>> id(x)
140707671078064
```

Changing the value of a variable that has immutable data simply makes the variable point to a new object with the updated value.

---

This is not the case with mutable types like `list`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> id(a), id(b)
(1886794896456, 1886794896456)
>>> b.append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

`a` is a `list` and is mutable, changing it using methods like `append` will actually mutate the value at address `1886794896456`. Since `b` also points to the same address, the value of `a` also gets updated.

---

A `deepcopy` creates a new object at a different memory location with the same value as its parameter, i.e. the object passed to it.

> I would like to know the reason why this design choice was made

This is simply because of how python is designed as an object oriented language. Similar behavior can be seen in java objects.

> I personally find this behavior counter-intuitive

Intuition comes from practice. Practicing one language cannot help with how other languages work, there are different design patterns and conventions for different languages and I think some amount of effort should be put in to learn what they are for the language we are about to use.

Comment: So I suppose the reason why the integers work as they do is to do as little work as possible, i.e. to acquire new memory resources only when I really need them. Is it the right line of reasoning?

Comment: @alessiolapolla: It's not really about memory efficiency. The "references for everything" design arises naturally when trying to design a language that allows complex data structures without explicit pointers, and then if you let basic numeric types be mutable in such a design, you end up having to make a zillion explicit copies all over the place to prevent ints and floats from changing unexpectedly. Numbers get passed around far too often for that to be practical.

Comment: `y` doesn't point to the same object as `x` after `y = x` just to save memory. It points to the same object because variable assignment *means* "evaluate the expression on the right and store the resulting reference in the variable on the left". Regardless of mutability or immutability, this assignment is *not allowed* to create a new object or to make `y` point somewhere other than where `x` points.

Answer (score 1):

`c = a` is neither a shallow copy nor a deep copy, no matter what `a` refers to. It's even shallower than that - it only copies a reference. Both `c` and `a` hold references to the same object after this assignment.

It is not possible to modify the value of an int in Python. When you use `+=` on an int, Python assigns a (reference to a) new int to wherever you retrieved the original int from.

For the first case, `a += 1` reassigns the `a` variable, while `b` and `c` continue to refer to the ints they referred to before the assignment.

For the second case, `a[0] += 1` reassigns cell 0 of the list `a` refers to. `b` continues to refer to the copy, which is unchanged, and `c` continues to refer to the same list `a` refers to. Since this list has changed state, the change is visible through the `c` variable.

---

Incidentally, `deepcopy` is designed to produce a deep copy, in the sense that (arbitrarily deep) modifications to the return value will not modify the argument, and vice versa. Since it is not possible to modify the value of an int in Python, an int counts as a (deep) copy of itself, and indeed, the `deepcopy` implementation simply returns its argument if its argument is an int.

```
>>> x = 1000
>>> copy.deepcopy(x) is x
True
```

Answer (score -1):

It is commonplace to link objects between them during copies and not primitives.

The difference between your snippets is that, in the second one, c is a copy of the list a, and a list is an object, so they are linked. Whereas c was a "copy" of a primitive in the first snippet, which doesn't link.

Comment: Ints are objects too in Python.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but they kept the convention that you can't link "primitives", even though they are technically objects too.

Comment: That's not what's going on. There are no "linked" copies. Rather, Python variables hold references to objects, and `c=a` causes `c` and `a` to hold references to the same object - it does not copy any objects.

Comment: What I am saying is that python's ints do not reference the same object in order to respect the convention you'll find in other programming languages such as java. a=0 b=a a+=1 print(b) : 0

Comment: That's not true. Two Python variables can reference the same int just fine, and indeed, `c` and `a` do reference the same int after `c=a` in the first snippet. They just *stop* referencing the same int after `a+=1`, because that assignment causes `a` to start referencing a different int.